# forEach loop works for android but not iPhone

Tags: javascript, html, iphone

I have a website with some links to parts of the page further down. To implement a smooth scroll on them, I use a querySelectorAll("a").forEach loop to loop through all the  tags which have a href and then add an eventListener for a "click", before linking it to the method which scrolls the page.
However, in this linking process, it seems that the href gets linked to the same variable every time, which means that by the end of the loop, all the links go to the href of the final  tag

```
document.querySelectorAll('a').forEach(anchor => {
    anchor.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    scrollToElm(anchor.getAttribute("href"));
    }
}
```

I think that the problem is that the onClick functions are all being paired to the same anchor variable, but I am not sure how to change this. It works on Windows and Android, but doesn't on iPhones.
Any help is much appreciated :)

Edit: The page scrolls when any of the links are clicked, they just all scroll to the anchor "#top" which is the last link on the page, which is why I think all eventListeners are being linked to the same anchor

Comment: look into ontouch events for iphone

Comment: It's not the event that isn't working, but the pointer for the element within the event

Comment: console.log the event and let us know what the difference is between windows and iphone